# HTML Canvas: Drawing grid below a plot

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, plot

I'm plotting a graph on a canvas and having trouble to draw the grid of the plot underneath the graph. My data points are drawn as rectangles (fillRect). When I first draw the graph and then draw the grid it works as expected, but since the grid is on the graph it doesnt look good. But when I draw the grid first and then plot the graph, all the grids disappear underneath.

I draw my plots as follows:

```
var plots = document.getElementsByClassName("PlotCanvas");
for (var x=0; x < tokens.length; x++)
    {
        var canvas = plots[x];
        canvas.width = arrayOfArrays[x].length;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        for(var point=1; point<arrayOfArrays[x].length; point++)
        {
            context.fillRect(point, arrayOfArrays[x][point],...);
        }
    }
```

Then draw the grids as:
function DrawGrids(plots)
{

```
    for(var count=0; count<plots.length; count++)
    {
        var ctx = plots[count].getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();

        for (var x = 0.5; x < plots[count].width; x += 20) {
            ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(x, plots[count].height);
        }
        for (var y = 0.5; y < plots[count].height; y += 20) {
            ctx.moveTo(0, y);
            ctx.lineTo(plots[count].width, y);
        }
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#eee";
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

Could someone suggest me how I can draw the grid underneath the plot. Or how to draw the graph such that it doesn't draw on the whole canvas thus disappearing the grid drawn earlier.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just behind the times, but I thought `fillRect` required four arguments.  You're only passing two.  What's up with that?

Comment: Thanks rob. Yes it does. I just didn't put them here for clarity because I have a rather messy calculation for last two arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over" to draw your grid behind your plots!**

```
// draw your plots here

// save the context
ctx.save();

// set compositing to "destination-over"
// New drawings are drawn behind the existing canvas content.
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";

// draw your grids behind your plots!
DrawGrids();

// restore the context
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Thank you markE. It worked. I wasn't aware of globalCompositeOperation property. Thank you.